# How do i check the length of this object?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, arrays

I'm using a heavily modified version of jquery-tokeninput

it's essentially a text input box that allows multiple tags just like stack overflow.

You can get a return value with all the tags currently in the input by running this:

`$("#no-custom-tokens").tokenInput("get")`

The problem is, it returns the following for me:

[image]

if i try to call `$("#no-custom-tokens").tokenInput("get").length` it just says undefined.

I need to check if there are any u1, u2, etc inside this object (basically.. is the input blank).

I have considered doing...

`if ($("#no-custom-tokens").tokenInput("get").u1.name != "")`

Except that if you delete tokens, then add 2 more, it doesnt start at u1, u2... it starts at u3 and u4.

:/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *"I need to check if there are any u1, u2, etc inside this object (basically.. is the input blank)."*

If you basically need to check for the existence of at least one property, and if the properties are enumerable, you can do this...

```
var has_props = false,
    obj = $("#no-custom-tokens").tokenInput("get");

for (var p in obj) {
    has_props = true;
    break;
}

console.log(has_props);
```

---

If you want to know how many, and again, if they're enumerable, you can use `Object.keys`...

```
var props_len = Object.keys($("#no-custom-tokens").tokenInput("get")).length;
```

---

You'll just need to shim it if you're supporting older browsers...

```
if (!Object.keys)
    Object.keys = function(o) {
        var keys = [];
        for (var k in o)
            if (o.hasOwnProperty(k))
                keys.push(k);

        return keys;
    };
```

Comment: This fails if the prototype of Object is augmented. You should check for `hasOwnProperty`.

Comment: @TorstenWalter: If the prototype of Object is augmented with enumerable properties, the only real solution is to remove the code that has corrupted the environment.

Comment: do i need to shim if im doing the first part? I wont need to check how many keys, only if they exist or not

Comment: @Tallboy: The prototype is how JavaScript does inheritance. Its object orientation is called "prototypal inheritance". If you add properties to the `prototype` object of a constructor function, then all objects created from that constructor will inherit those properties. Since all Objects inherit from the `Object` constructor's prototype, any properties added to `Object.prototype` will show up on all objects. If you do `Object.prototype.foo = "bar";`, then create an empty object `var my_obj = {};`, if you do `alert(my_obj.foo);`, it will give you `"bar"`. It'll also show up with `for-in`.

Comment: MaxArt, not that I would endorse the practice but you'll never know which framework or lib does what, so checking os good to be on the safe side.

Comment: @TorstenWalter: It's a developer's responsibility to know. Using a guard on *every* enumeration just because some library code *might* have done something that is trivial to test for, is just not sensible. Not to mention that it adds code, slows down enumeration, and *prevents* you from enumerating prototyped properties of custom constructors when desired.

Comment: @am not i am, you are right. It depends on the use case, most of the time (for me at least) I am interested in the objects properties I am iterating over so I _have_ to check anyway. If I want all properties, including those from the prototype chain, I won't check. The responsibility to know is fine for a small project, but if you develop for a website with literally hundreds of developers and almost as much third party libraries and scripts, you want your code to be bulletproof so advertisers or mashups don't render your site unusable.

Comment: @TorstenWalter: I do see what you mean, but WRT hundreds of developers working on a site, I'd mandate an uncorrupted environment. It's a simple one-time or periodic test, and then just a matter of tracking down the developer responsible for corrupting the environment. WRT 3rd party libraries, I think the criteria should be the same. WRT advertisers, etc, I definitely see your point.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like it's returning as an object, not an array, so there is no .length method. If you just want to check if anything's in the object, you can try to loop through the object and set a flag if it finds anything. So:

```
var isEmpty = true;
var tokens = $("#no-custom-tokens").tokenInput("get");
for (var i in tokens) {
    isEmpty = false;
    break;
}
if (isEmpty) {
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Check if it's empty:

```
function isEmpty(obj) {
    for (var i in obj) {
        if (obj.hasOwnProperty(i)) return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Check its length:

```
function objectLength(obj) {
    var size = 0;
    for (var i in obj) {
        if (obj.hasOwnProperty(i)) ++size;
    }
    return size;
}

// or:

function objectLength(obj) {
    return Object.keys(obj).length;
}
```

Comment: Or check if `Object.keys` exists, and if not, define it (won't be the exact same thing, though).